# How to do a multicast DNS query in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, dns

I have a range of webcams that are on the network. Their maker uses mDNS/multicast DNS to communicate with "_axis-video._tcp.local".

I used their own software with the packet "MDNS 224.0.0.251 210 Standard query 0x0000  PTR _axis-video._tcp.local, "QM" question" according to wireshark.

How can I send out a mDNS packet with this PTR included in vb.net? I tried Bonjour, but using its sample code would give me an error about binding the endpoint on the second try of sending the mDNS (and it doesn't like the ".local" part of the request).

The closest I've found is this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304441/mdns-discovery-issue

It was really helpful, but I didn't see a "DnsQuery" class equivalent in vb.net. Is there a way to do that? is there a better method that might work?

For ease, here's a vb.net "converted" version of what that question had:

```
  Dim query As New DnsQuery() 'has no definition!

    query.AsStandardQuery().AddQuestion(question) 
    query.Header.idL = 0


    Dim queryByte = query.ToByteArray()
    Dim client As New UdpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    Dim ipend As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("224.0.0.251"), 5353) 'multicast
    client.Send(queryByte, queryByte.Length, ipend)
```

Comment: Looks like standard Windows API to me.  [This page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682016(v=vs.85).aspx) took about 3 seconds to find on Google.  Looks like the definition is just an API wrapper.

Comment: That's in C++ though. How would I convert that? is there some information on that I could look at? I don't know anything about "_In_" or "PCTSTR".

Comment: There is some information [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dnsapi.dnsquery), along with a few VB examples.  I don't know how far that will go toward solving your problem though.

Comment: I'll take anything at this point. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck!  It's a long road from API to VB code if you haven't done it before!